# sed print n'th 'a' to m'th 'b' inclusive

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Is there a way to print 4th match of 'four' to 8th match of 'eight' only using cat and sed?

I'm given to use =, N, p, q, s as hints, but not sure how to utilize those

For example,

```
$ cat foo
1
2
3
4
5-
alkjvearv four
four
asdfasd four 
----fourth asdf
qlvkjqrvlj eight
5+
6
7
8
9
eight eight eight
10
11
12 eight
13 eight
eight qorivjqoerijv
----this is eighth
eight
15

$ cat foo | sed ~
----fourth asdf
qlvkjqrvlj eight
5+
6
7
8
9
eight eight eight
10
11
12 eight
13 eight
eight qorivjqoerijv
----this is eighth
```

this is as far as I've got

```
$ cat foo | sed -n '/four/,/eight/p'
alkjvearv four
four
asdfasd four 
----fourth asdf
qlvkjqrvlj eight
```

Comment: Could some of the 8 matches of `eight` appear before some of the 4 matches of `four`?  Are you using POSIX `sed` or GNU `sed`?  I think GNU `sed` has some extra features in this area, but I work to POSIX `sed` so I've not memorized them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and yes, "eight" can come before "four", and I'm using posix sed

Comment: Especially with the three occurrences of `eight` on a single line to be counted as 3 (rather than counting lines containing one or more occurrences of `eight`), it is going to be hard.  I'd rather tackle it in Awk or Perl than Sed.  It probably can be done, but the brain-ache I'm getting thinking about it means I need to head off to bed ('tis that time of day where I am).

Comment: @Jake, is it necessary to use only `sed` and `cat`? Then could you please post sample expected output too in your post and let us know.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you that Perl or Awk will get this done far easily. but I'm only allowed to use sed and cat in this case. Thanks and good night!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, only sed and cat :(

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How would you tackle it given any number of occurrence on each line is counted as one?

Comment: I'm not sure — that's why my brain's aching.  I don't see `cat` providing any benefit, but I may be missing something.  I don't see how `cat` could expand on what `sed` can do anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree, `cat` doesn't do much other than piping the file into sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it matches exactly  what you need as your question is quite imprecise, but it may give you an idea. Of course this solution is not something you should use (use `awk`).

The strings `uuid1` and `uuid2` may be replaced by any two strings that are not present already in the file.

```
sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' \
    -e 's/four/uuid1/' -e 's/four/uuid1/' -e 's/four/uuid1/' \
    -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' \
    -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' foo |
sed -n '/four/,/eight/p;/eight/q' |
sed 's/uuid1/four/g;s/uuid2/eight/g'
```

Returns :

```
----fourth asdf
qlvkjqrvlj eight
5+
6
7
8
9
eight eight eight
10
11
12 eight
13 eight
eight qorivjqoerijv
----this is eighth
```

which I think is correct.

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155810) and this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264977) helped me.

---

Command explained :

`sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x'`

From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155810)

> The sed commands H;1h;$!d;x read the whole file in.
>
> Because the above does not use any GNU extension, it should work on
>   BSD (OSX) sed. Note, thought, that this approach requires a sed that
>   can handle long lines. GNU sed should be fine. Those using a non-GNU
>   version of sed should test its ability to handle long lines.

```
-e 's/four/uuid1/' -e 's/four/uuid1/' -e 's/four/uuid1/' \
-e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' \
-e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' -e 's/eight/uuid2/' foo
```

Then I replace the first three `four` to `uuid1` and the first seven `eight` to `uuid2`.

As @JonathanLeffler said, it becomes very ugly if you increase the number of substitutions, but I didn't find any workaround for POSIX sed versions, I used the command from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155810).

> If GNU sed is not available and you want to change the first 3
>   occurrences of old to new, then use three s commands:
>
> This works well when k is a small number but scales poorly to large k.

`sed -n '/four/,/eight/p;/eight/q'` — don't print by default; from the first `four` to the first `eight`, print the line; when you find `eight`, quit.

I tried this first : `sed -n '/four/,/eight/p'` but it could return rows after the section that is supposed to be printed. I used [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264962/print-lines-of-a-file-between-two-matching-patterns/264977#264977) to fix the issue.

This command selects the line between the first `four` and the first `eight` occurrence.

`sed 's/uuid1/four/g;s/uuid2/eight/g'` I replace the uuids to their original values. I do it even for `uuid1` as the third `four` may be on the same line as the fourth one.

Comment: Well done!  I think you should explain what your code does, particularly the first `sed` command.  AFAICS, it caches the entire input into the hold space, then at the end edits 3 lots of `four` to `uuid1`, 7 lots of `eight` to `uuid2` and the outputs the result (the edited copy of the whole file) ready for the subsequent `sed` commands to process.  The only snag with this is that the first command gets even more unwieldy if the numbers change from 4 and 8 to 40 and 80.

Comment: @CorentinLimier Thank you for your effort, and I'm sorry that the question was rather unclear. Your answer was precise and now I can clearly see why `sed` isn't an optimal choice to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;h;s/four/&/4;tb;$d;N;ba;:b;s/eight/&/8;tc;$d;N;bb;:c;x;s/.*\n//;G;s/$/\n/;s/^\([^\n]*\n\).*\1/\1/;s/\n$//;q' file
```

This uses the substitution command to check if the start/end strings have been accounted for as the input file is processed. The command `s/someString/&/n` replaces the n'th occurrence of `someString` by itself. The substitution command also sets an internal flag to true if a substitution has been successful. The `t` command allows sed to test the internal flag and jump to another point in the sed command script e.g. `ta` will jump to the point in the sed script where `:a` occurs if the last substitution was successful. The internal flag is reset to false immediately a jump has been made or a new sed cycle invoked. This mechanism is used to count the arbitrary strings for the start/end conditions. Once both conditions have been met and the section before the start boundary removed, the processing of the input file can be terminated and the result printed or not printed out.

N.B. The deletion of the section of text before the start condition can lead to a host of edge cases. To simplify them, a newline is appended and subsequently removed, from the eventual result.

An easier but prone to possible error solution:

```
sed -z 's/four/\x00&/4;s/eight/\x00&/8' file |
sed '/\x00four/,/\x00eight/!d;s/\x00\(four\)/\1/;s/\x00\(eight\)/\1/'
```